# Extracting Specific text string from PDF

Tags: string, pdf, text, match, extract

First post here, and i'm a near total newbie so please be kind.
I am trying to implement a piece of code that will allow a user to import a pdf, search for specific text strings and export them all into a PDF.

I have looked at similar answers, but they often seem to be based off of knowing the pdf structure. For context, I am trying to extract all occurrences of where an ID number is used in the following format - AAA01234567 (3 letters, 8 numbers). The PDFs are all downloaded files with OCR.

I have tried to utilise pdfplumber and PyPDF2 to do so, but i'm getting struck on the syntax.

```
pip install PyPDF2
import PyPDF2

pdfFileObj = open('Transcript 29 July 2021_1.pdf', 'rb')

from re import search

match = search('[a-zA-Z]{3}\d{8}', string)
match

<re.Match object; span=(0, 7), match='RBK0000'>
```

I'm getting some output, but only a single ID rather than the entire list within the document.

I would be grateful for any help you can provide!
Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am struggling with, I do not know what I need to add to read more than one.

Comment: There's `re.findall`.